# Side-by-side Venn diagram using Vennerable

Tags: r, r-grid, venn-diagram

I am trying to put two Venn diagrams in one single graph, i.e. I am using par(mfrow=c(1,2)) at the very beginning. However, when I use the `Venn()` function in the `Vennerable` package:

```
VennCompare = Venn(SetNames = c("A", "B", "C"), Weight = c(0, 38, 1, 0, 1, 80, 0, 14))
pdf(file="Venn.pdf", width=12, height=6)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(VennCompare, doWeights=FALSE)
plot(VennCompare, doWeights=TRUE, show = list(SetLabels = TRUE, Faces = FALSE))
dev.off()
```

The resultant pdf file contains 2 pages, and each page has a single Venn diagram.

How can I put the two diagrams into a single page (i.e. side-by-side)?

Comment: Vennerable seems to use grid graphics instead of R base graphics, so par(mfrow=c(1,2)) wont work.

Comment: @Hemmo: thanks! so how can I make side-by-side plots in the grid environment?

Comment: I've been trying to plot these using standard `grid` methods and it looks like `plot(VennCompare)` does not respond to view port methods.

Comment: @BryanHanson: that's exactly what I got just now... it's not working if I pass p1 = plot(VennCompare)...

Comment: I think you may have to contact the package maintainer.  They have have to add support for a viewport argument, and they seem to have the equivalent of a newpage in their method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already discussed in comments, Vennerable uses grid graphics and fixes the grid parameters inside of the package functions. You should probably ask kindly from package maintainers if they could add this kind of functionality in their packages, but in a meantime I offer you a Sketchof a hack which allows you to do what you want:

The first  command allows you to edit the function called `makevp.eqsc` which seems to contain the grid definitions:

```
trace("makevp.eqsc",edit=TRUE)
```

Original code looks like this:

```
function (xrange, yrange) 
{
    pushViewport(plotViewport(name = "Vennmar", c(1, 1, 1, 1)))
    pushViewport(viewport(name = "Vennlay", layout = grid.layout(1, 
        1, widths = diff(xrange), heights = diff(yrange), respect = TRUE)))
    pushViewport(viewport(name = "Vennvp", layout.pos.row = 1, 
        layout.pos.col = 1, xscale = xrange, yscale = yrange))
}
```

The most relevant parts are `grid.layout`, which tells you what kind of grid you want to draw. Also layout.pos.row and layout.pos.col are important, they tell in which position to draw. Change the code for example like this:

```
function (xrange, yrange) 
{
    pushViewport(plotViewport(name = "Vennmar", c(1, 1, 1, 1)))
    pushViewport(viewport(name = "Vennlay", layout = grid.layout(2, 
        1, widths = diff(xrange), heights = diff(yrange), respect = TRUE)))
    pushViewport(viewport(name = "Vennvp", layout.pos.row = number, 
        layout.pos.col = 1, xscale = xrange, yscale = yrange))
}
```

Now you will get two stacked graphs, like this:

```
number<-1 #change the argument inside of makevp.eqsc
plot(VennCompare, doWeights=FALSE)
number<-2
plot(VennCompare, doWeights=TRUE, 
  show = list(SetLabels = TRUE, Faces = FALSE),add=TRUE) #note add=TRUE
```

This doesn't look really nice, but by modifying `makevp.eqsc` you can probably archieve more nice results.

Comment: @Hemmo: thanks man! that works very well: I modified your parameters a little bit to get 1-by-2 side-by-side plots :)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't install that package, but a trick that might help here is to use grid.grab to capture the drawing into a grob that can be placed elsewhere,

```
library(grid)

myplot <- function(){

  pushViewport(viewport(x=0.5,width=1, just=0.5))
  grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill=grey(runif(1, 0.2, 0.8))))
  grid.points()
  popViewport()

}

p1 <- grid.grabExpr(myplot())
p2 <- grid.grabExpr(myplot())

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

Comment: This works but you don't need `pushViewport` and `popViewport` parts, at least for me using Vennerable 3.1.0.9000. Doing `grid.grabExpr` and using `grid.arrange` worked fine on the `plot` function directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
v <- Venn(n=2)
plot(v)
grid.text("Title", vp = viewport(x=0.5, y=.9, w=unit(1, "npc"), h=unit(1, "npc")))
```