# Draw weights and % on Venn Diagram in R (Vennerable Package)

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have some trouble/ I need to draw Venn Diagram and print weight values and percentage together. Now I'm writing this code:

```
library(Vennerable)
> areas
   00    01    10    11 
38596  6024 40696  8971
VennSet <- Venn(SetNames = category, Weight = areas)
VennList <- compute.Venn(VennSet, doWeights = TRUE)
gp <- VennThemes(VennList)
plot(VennList, gpList=gp, show = list(FaceText = c("signature", "weight"), DarkMatter = TRUE))
```

Result:
[image]

Then I wanted to change the values in the last line.

```
pcentFun <- function(x) {
100 * (x /sum(x))
}
areasPcent <- round(pcentFun(areas), digits=2)
VennList@FaceLabels$Signature <- paste(areasPcent, "%", sep="")
```

Result:
[image]

I have printed percentages, but lost the weight.
Here is the structure of the object:

```
> str(VennList)
Formal class 'VennDrawing' [package "Vennerable"] with 11 slots
  ..@ universe        : num [1:2, 1:2] -209 152 -150 150
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ SetLabels       :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ Label: chr [1:2] "Glia.LAM.mf_min.bound" "Glia.HP1.mf_min.bound"
  .. ..$ x    : num [1:2] -54.2 54.2
  .. ..$ y    : num [1:2] 128.3 71.6
  .. ..$ hjust:Class 'AsIs'  chr [1:2] "center" "center"
  .. ..$ vjust: chr [1:2] "bottom" "bottom"
  ..@ FaceLabels      :'data.frame':    4 obs. of  6 variables:
  .. ..$ FaceName : chr [1:4] "01" "10" "11" "DarkMatter"
  .. ..$ Signature: chr [1:4] "40.93%" "6.39%" "43.16%" "9.51%"
  .. ..$ x        : num [1:4] 97.4 -97.4 28.3 123.3
  .. ..$ y        : num [1:4] 0.00 1.19e-14 4.23e-15 1.26e+02
  .. ..$ hjust    : chr [1:4] "centre" "centre" "centre" "right"
  .. ..$ vjust    : chr [1:4] "centre" "centre" "centre" "top"
  ..@ setList         :List of 2
  .. ..$ Set1: chr [1:2] "i24|i23|1" "i23|i24|1"
  .. ..$ Set2: chr [1:2] "i24|i23|2" "i23|i24|2"
  ..@ nodeList        :List of 2
  .. ..$ i23: num [1, 1:2] 50.9 69
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "i23"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. ..$ i24: num [1, 1:2] 50.9 -69
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "i24"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ recentChanges   : chr [1:2] "c11|i24|1" "i24|i23|1"
  ..@ edgeList        :List of 4
  .. ..$ i24|i23|1:Formal class 'VDedgeSector' [package "Vennerable"] with 9 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ radius   : num 126
  .. .. .. ..@ fromTheta: num 5.7
  .. .. .. ..@ toTheta  : num 0.581
  .. .. .. ..@ centre   : num [1:2] -54.2 0
  .. .. .. ..@ hand     : num 1
  .. .. .. ..@ from     : chr "i24"
  .. .. .. ..@ to       : chr "i23"
  .. .. .. ..@ visible  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..@ bb       : num [1:2, 1:2] -179.9 71.5 -125.7 125.7
  .. ..$ i24|i23|2:Formal class 'VDedgeSector' [package "Vennerable"] with 9 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ radius   : num 69.1
  .. .. .. ..@ fromTheta: num 4.66
  .. .. .. ..@ toTheta  : num 1.62
  .. .. .. ..@ centre   : num [1:2] 54.2 0
  .. .. .. ..@ hand     : num 1
  .. .. .. ..@ from     : chr "i24"
  .. .. .. ..@ to       : chr "i23"
  .. .. .. ..@ visible  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..@ bb       : num [1:2, 1:2] -14.9 123.3 -69.1 69.1
  .. ..$ i23|i24|1:Formal class 'VDedgeSector' [package "Vennerable"] with 9 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ radius   : num 126
  .. .. .. ..@ fromTheta: num 0.581
  .. .. .. ..@ toTheta  : num -0.581
  .. .. .. ..@ centre   : num [1:2] -54.2 0
  .. .. .. ..@ hand     : num 1
  .. .. .. ..@ from     : chr "i23"
  .. .. .. ..@ to       : chr "i24"
  .. .. .. ..@ visible  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..@ bb       : num [1:2, 1:2] -179.9 71.5 -125.7 125.7
  .. ..$ i23|i24|2:Formal class 'VDedgeSector' [package "Vennerable"] with 9 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ radius   : num 69.1
  .. .. .. ..@ fromTheta: num 1.62
  .. .. .. ..@ toTheta  : num -1.62
  .. .. .. ..@ centre   : num [1:2] 54.2 0
  .. .. .. ..@ hand     : num 1
  .. .. .. ..@ from     : chr "i23"
  .. .. .. ..@ to       : chr "i24"
  .. .. .. ..@ visible  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..@ bb       : num [1:2, 1:2] -14.9 123.3 -69.1 69.1
  ..@ faceList        :List of 4
  .. ..$ DarkMatter: chr [1:2] "-i24|i23|1" "-i23|i24|2"
  .. ..$ 11        : chr [1:2] "i24|i23|2" "i23|i24|1"
  .. ..$ 10        : chr [1:2] "i24|i23|1" "-i24|i23|2"
  .. ..$ 01        : chr [1:2] "i23|i24|2" "-i23|i24|1"
  ..@ faceSignature   :List of 4
  .. ..$ DarkMatter: chr "DarkMatter"
  .. ..$ 11        : chr "11"
  .. ..$ 10        : chr "10"
  .. ..$ 01        : chr "01"
  ..@ IndicatorWeight : num [1:4, 1:3] 0 1 0 1 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "00" "10" "01" "11"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Glia.LAM.mf_min.bound" "Glia.HP1.mf_min.bound" ".Weight"
  ..@ IntersectionSets: list()
```

And its output

```
> VennList
A Venn object on 2 sets named
Glia.LAM.mf_min.bound,Glia.HP1.mf_min.bound 
   00    10    01    11 
38596 40696  6024  8971 
          from  to         type npoints              centre hand
i24|i23|1  i24 i23 VDedgeSector      NA -54.2116651664673,0    1
i24|i23|2  i24 i23 VDedgeSector      NA  54.2116651664673,0    1
i23|i24|1  i23 i24 VDedgeSector      NA -54.2116651664673,0    1
i23|i24|2  i23 i24 VDedgeSector      NA  54.2116651664673,0    1
          X1        X2
i23 50.89514  69.00766
i24 50.89514 -69.00766
                           faces
DarkMatter -i24|i23|1;-i23|i24|2
11           i24|i23|2;i23|i24|1
10          i24|i23|1;-i24|i23|2
01          i23|i24|2;-i23|i24|1
                  sig
DarkMatter DarkMatter
11                 11
10                 10
01                 01
     paste.face..collapse.......
Set1         i24|i23|1;i23|i24|1
Set2         i24|i23|2;i23|i24|2
```

Who has any idea how to output both weights and percentages?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what I wanted. But also has a right to exist.

```
areasPcent <- round(pcentFun(areas), digits=2)
VennSet <- Venn(SetNames = category, Weight = areas)
VennList <- compute.Venn(VennSet, doWeights = TRUE)
VennList_pc <- VennList
for (i in c(1:length(areasPcent))) {
    position <- grep(names(areasPcent)[i], VennList_pc@FaceLabels$Signature)
    VennList_pc@FaceLabels$Signature[position] <- paste(areasPcent[i], "%", sep="")
}
gp <- VennThemes(VennList)
pdf(file=file.path(paste("Venn Diagram between ", v2, " from ", v1, ".pdf", sep="")), width=8, height=12.76)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
par(mai=c(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5))
rowNumberMakevp <<- 1
plot(VennList, gpList=gp)
rowNumberMakevp <<- 2
plot(VennList_pc, gpList=gp, show = list(FaceText = c("signature"), DarkMatter = TRUE))
dev.off()
```

I'm using solution for multiple diagram from [side-by-side Venn diagram using Vennerable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315369/4424721)

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was asked years ago, I believe it's better to share the answer that worked well for me. I actually found an easier way to do it (using line breaks betwee the `areas` and `areasPcent`), as follows:

```
VennList@FaceLabels$Signature <- paste0(areas, "\n", areasPcent, "%")
plot(VennList, gpList=gp, show = list(FaceText = c("signature"), DarkMatter = TRUE))
```

Notice that you need to show only the `"signature"` in the `FaceText`.

Hope it helps.